# How to remove name of an app that appears in blue color on site when you deploy an app?

Tags: office-365

When I deply my sharepoint hosted app there is this text (SharePointApp2) appering.How can I remove it?
Thx!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS would work, or you could give your project a prettier name so it looks better.

```
#DeltaPlaceHolderSiteName{
 display:none;
}
```